# Parse.com crashreporting Symbols with Robovm

Tags: ios, parse-platform, symbols, robovm

I've implemented the crashreporting into the parse bindings and am able to receive crashes on iOS in Parse.
Currently what it says is not useful at all because it's not symbolicated. Until now I've not been able to upload the symbols because of the following error:

Using command: 
    parse symbols applicationName --path=""
returns:
    "Do not understand symbol at "

Where  is the path to the application.app.dSYM file created by Robovm.

My first question is if I do get the symbols into the parse dashboard will I see anything useful data from behind the ahead of time compiler (actual java exceptions or something similar) or will it be unuseable for decent debugging purposes. If it is useful, does anyone have a clue as to how to upload the symbols file created by Robovm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fixed by using the following command:

parse symbols applicationName -p "/path/to/dsym/"

Comment: How long did it take for Parse.com to show your method names on the crash reports? Did it show them for past crashes, or only new crashes? Thanks!

Comment: it should update past crashes too. However I've also had it take some time to do so.